# how to pass more types arguments into method with one parameter

Tags: java, oop, parameters, interface, polymorphism

I have several classes with differently object type cat, dog and horse. I have 
one root class where is method doSomethig with only one parameter which I want to call in rest of classes. How to write the method without type conflict. This is only example.

```
Cat cat; 
Dog dog;
Horse horse;

protected void doSomething(one parameter){
  cat.doMeow();
  dog.doBark();
  horse.run();
}
```

Comment: What type conflict?

Comment: I call this method from the rest of classes if I in root class set parameter e.g. doSomething(Dog xyz) I can sent Cat or horse to this method from Cat or Horse class.

Comment: Do you have a base class for `Cat`, `Dog` and `Horse`? Something like `Animal` ?

Comment: @alexander.egger I don't think that would help to OP, since doSomething() wants to call a different method depending on the type.  This sounds to me like a case where creating an overload per type is the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes but is more complex project and I cannot create new instance of cat or dog in this class

Comment: Question is unclear - add more code to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to extend parent class Animal where there would be doSomething(one parameter) and then in subclasses call `super()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the signature is fixed for just one parameter. But you need to have access to `cat`, `dog` and `horse`? In that case, you need to adjust `one` to be a `parameter object`.

(Also, it should start with an upper case letter, as general accepted code style)

```
public class one
{
    private Cat cat;
    private Dog dog;
    private Horse horse;

    public one(Cat cat, Dog dog, Horse horse)
    {
        this.cat = cat;
        this.dog = dog;
        this.horse = horse;
    }

    public Cat getCat()
    {
        return this.cat
    }

    // getDog(), getHorse()
}
```

Then use the getter methods in the doSomething method

```
protected void doSomething(one parameter){
    parameter.getCat().doMeow();
    parameter.getDog().doBark();
    parameter.getHorse().run();
}
```

Calling it like:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    one animals = new one(new Cat(), new Dog(), new Horse());
    doSomething(animals); // if same class or myInstance.doSomething(animals) if another class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force solution would be to pass an Object, e.g. of type `Animal` and check the type in the method, and call the appropriate method based on the result of the type check:

```
protected void doSOmething(Animal an Animal) {
  if( anAnimal instanceof Horse)
    ((Horse) anAnimal).run();
  else if( anAnimal instanceof Dog )
    ((Dog) anAnimal).bark();
  else ...
}
```

However, this is considered to be bad style, because the method has too much knowledge about Horses, Dogs, and such.
It would be better if `Animal` had an abstract method `doDefaultAction()` which is overwritten by the Horse as a call to `run()`, by the dog as a call to `bark()`, and so on.

```
abstract class Animal {
  abstract void doDefaultAction(Animal anAnimal);
}

class Horse extends Animal {
  @Override
  void doDefaultAction(Animal anAnimal) {
    ((Horse) anAnimal).run();
  }

  void run() { /* do some running */ }
}
```

In your method `doSomething()` you would simply call `anAnimal.doDefaultAction()` without need to know what the default action for the animal might be.
If the abstract `Animal` class does not do something else you might also consider to use an `interface Animal` instead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a common interface and call the interface method. For example:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void act();
}

public class Cat implements Animal {

    public void doMeow() { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void act() {
        doMeow();
    }
}

public class Dog implements Animal {

    public void doBark() { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void act() {
        doBark();
    }

}
```

Then the `doSomething` method could polymorphically call the `act` method:

```
protected void doSomething(Animal animal) {
    animal.act();
}
```

Depending on which object is passed (e.g. `Cat` or `Dog`), the behavior of `doSomething` will change.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the classic OO inheritance example. A simple solution works like this:

```
public class AnimalExample {

    interface Animal {
        void action();
    }

    public static class Cat implements Animal{

        @Override
        public void action() {
            System.out.println("meow");
        }
    }

    public static class Dog implements Animal{

        @Override
        public void action() {
            System.out.println("bark");
        }
    }

    public static class Horse implements Animal{

        @Override
        public void action() {
            System.out.println("run");
        }
    }

    static void doSomething(Animal animal){
        animal.action();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Horse horse = new Horse();

        doSomething(cat);
        doSomething(dog);
        doSomething(horse);

    }
}
```